# Running and configuring mqtt broker with docker composer

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the documentation of docker composer version 3, from what I understood, to run some commands after a container has started I need to add the "command" tag as follows:

```
version: "3"

services:

    broker:
         image: "toke/mosquitto"
         restart: always
         ports:
             - "1883:1883"
             - "9001:9001"
         command: ["cd /etc/mosquitto", "echo \"\" > mosquitto.pwd", "mosquitto_passwd -b /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.pwd user pass", "echo \"password_file mosquitto.pwd\" >> mosquitto.conf", "echo \"allow_anonymous false\" >> mosquitto.conf"]
```

The log returns `/usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 5: exec: cd /etc/mosquitto: not found`

A workaround could be specify in the composer file what dockerfile to run and add the commands that should run there, so I created one dockerfile:

```
FROM toke/mosquitto

WORKDIR .

EXPOSE 1883:1883 9001:9001

ENTRYPOINT cd /etc/mosquitto
ENTRYPOINT echo "" > mosquitto.pwd
ENTRYPOINT mosquitto_passwd -b mosquitto.pwd usertest passwordtest
ENTRYPOINT echo "password_file mosquitto.pwd" >> mosquitto.conf
ENTRYPOINT echo "allow_anonymous false" >> mosquitto.conf
```

The container's keep restarting and the log doesn't return anything. I've also tried changing the "ENTRYPOINT" for "CMD" with no changing in the output.
As an addend specifying the docker composer file to use a specific dockerfile it fails to parse and says:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.broker: 'dockerfile'
```

As in it can't parse or doesn't understand "dockerfile" tag. Does anyone know how to configure a dockerfile or even docker-composer to run the commands intended in this post to configure a mqtt broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `command` entry in the compose file is not a list of commands to run, it's a single command and it's arguments

e.g. to run `mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

```
command: ["mosquitto", "-c", "/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf"]
```

As for the Dockerfile, There should only be one `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`. If you want to run multiple commands then you should create a shell script to do run them, add it to the container then use `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` to run the script.

Comment: Thank you hardillb for your answer, just to complete I was able to copy the bash file into the container using the tag volume and executing it with the tag command, it shows that is echoing the first file in the bash file but it can't simply do a listing with "ls" it says `: not found /etc/mosquitto/broker-config.sh: 3: /etc/mosquitto/broker-config.sh: ls` would know about that?